# Как задать размер QVBoxLayout

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Есть слой с двумя кнопками. Все создается программно:

```
    ui->setupUi(this);

    layout = new QVBoxLayout(this);
    setLayout(layout);

    for (int i(0); i < (list.size() + 1); i++){
        QPushButton *button = new QPushButton(this);
        layout->addWidget(button);
    }

    lGeometry.setRect(281, 314, 650, 460);/
    layout->setObjectName("mainLayot");
    layout->setGeometry(lGeometry);

    qDebug() << layout->geometry();
```

При запуске программы слой все равно открывается на весь виджет, а `qDebug()` выдает:

> QRect(0,0 824x557)

Пробовал использовать функцию `layout->setSizeConstraint(QLayout::SetFixedSize);` но тогда все сворачивается до минимума и главный виджет и слой и кнопки. Подскажите, как быть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А зачем задавать размеры Layout? Задавайте размеры и геометрию `QWidget`, и в него устанавливайте Layout. Layout займёт всё свободное пространство виджета и Вы получите искомое.

Comment: Да в том то и проблема, что мне не нужно чтоб он занимал все свободное пространство. А хотелось бы так, чтоб он находился по серединке в четко указанной точке. Ноя уже выяснил что так не делается. Нужно все равнять спейсерами и стречами.

Comment: @Madisson, так я Вам и говорю — поместите в эту точку виджет, и в него уже засуньте layout.

Answer (score 1):

Я решил так:
Сделал QVBoxLayout, в него пихнул виджет, содержащий необходимый Layout. 
За счёт виджета можно редактировать чёткий размер, а за счёт внешнего Layout-а - выравнивание.